Filter data based on relation presence in supabase
I have 2 tables, Challenges & UserResponse, defined like this with prisma:
model Challenge {
  id           Int            @id @default(autoincrement())
  title        String
  description  String
  createdById  String
  createdBy    User           @relation(fields: [createdById], references: [id])
  options      Option[]
  UserResponse UserResponse[]
}

model UserResponse {
  id          Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  userId      String
  challengeId Int
  optionId    Int
  challenge   Challenge @relation(fields: [challengeId], references: [id])
  option      Option    @relation(fields: [optionId], references: [id])
  user        User      @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])

  @@unique([userId, challengeId])
}

Using supabase I would like to get all challenges for whom there is no UserResponse with userId: 123.
I came up with this query, but it only filters UserResponses not Challenges:
  const { data: challenges, error } = await supabaseClient
    .from('Challenge')
    .select('*, Option(*), UserResponse(userId)')
    .neq('UserResponse.userId', userId);

Basically, I don't want the users to see the challenges that they have already responded to.
